# Javascript asynchronous function not returning

Tags: javascript, scoping

I'm trying to filter documents inside an array. I have a asynchronous getter function that gets a user, and inside that i should return the document if the user is the same as the current session user.

The problem is that the return function doesn't work inside that getter, since it returns a promise. I don't understand Synch and Async very well but if i put it outside like this:

```
documents = documents.filter(document => {

    if(document.user.id != this.user.id) {
        return document 
    }

})
```

It returns just fine

```
            documents = documents.filter(document => {

                    if(document.user.id != this.user.id) {
                        getter.getNextUserToSign(document.id).then(res => {                            
                            if( res != null) {
                                //if next user == session user
                                if(res.id == this.user.id){
                                    /*This log shows*/
                                    console.log("is equal to " + res.id)
                                    /*but this return doesnt work*/
                                    return document

                                }else{
                                    console.log(res.id + " is not equal")
                                }
                            }else{
                                console.log("is null")
                            }

                        })

                    }

            })
```

It goes until the log saying "is equal to {id}" but the document is not returned.

Comment: You can not treat an asynchronous method like it is synchronous. The filter code does not wait for the asynchronous method to complete.

Comment: `res => {` wraps around your return statement, so you are only return out of that function

Answer (score 1):

As @JClassic said, you're returning from the inner anonymous function, not the main function. If getNextUserToSign is async and returns a promise, as it looks like it does, then the filter (which is synchronous) will continue iterating even before the first call to that is complete.

What you can do instead is a bit of refactoring. Instead of directly filtering your document array, you can map it onto those getNextUserToSign promises, and then use Promise.all() to wait for all of those promises to resolve (i.e. complete). The `.then` callback on the `Promise.all` will be passed an array that's basically your `res` values for each of the documents in the same order, and then you can filter the main array based on its corresponding values in the results array.

So a refactor like that might look something like this (I took out your console.logs for clarity, you can put them back if you want them):

```
documents = documents.filter(document => document.user.id !== this.user.id);

const promises = documents.map(document => getter.getNextUserToSign(document.id));

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  documents = documents.filter((document, i) => {
    return results[i] && results[i].id === this.$session.get('user').id;
  });
});
```

So first it filters out the documents that have the current user's ID, since that doesn't require async. Then it maps the remainders to their promises. Then, when *all* the promises have resolved, it filters the documents array based on the results from those promises.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i read a bit on javascript sync but i still don't understand it too well. I tried your suggestion but the return inside the Promise is still not being inserted in documents as it should, only the first filter() is working.

Comment: I bet it is working; are you trying to access the final documents array outside the Promise callback? If so, that's your problem: you're still trying to access it before the Promises have finished resolving, and so also before the second filter is running. Since you have async operations here, you can't access the array until AFTER they have completed, i.e. inside the `.then` callback.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a scoping issue but more of a trying to handle an asynchronous operation in synchronous manner.

You are using a getter which returns a `promise` which is an `asynchronous` operation and while you're expecting your getter to return you your document, it returns a promise instead.

In order to solve it you can use a combination of `async/await` and `promises` to resolve your document, something like this probably!

```
documents = documents.filter(async document => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (document.user.id !== this.user.id) {
      getter.getNextUserToSign(document.id).then(res => {
        if (res !== null) {

          if (res.id == this.$session.get("user").id) {
            resolve(document);
          }
        }
        reject(res.id + " is not equal");
      });
    }
  });
});
```